# JasperReports export to Json not handling "null" correctly

Tags: jasper-reports

When I use Json metadata on my report and export to Json, a text field whose expression evaluates to `null`, instead of printing this: `{... "field"=null ...}` is printing this: `{... "field"="null" ...}`.

JasperReports is handling `null` as the String `"null"`. If I set the field to "blank when null" this is printed: `{... "field"="" ...}`.

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have null values in the JSON output by copying the text field expression as expression for the net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.data property.  As in

```
<textField>
    <reportElement ...>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" value="FieldThatCanBeNull"/>
        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.data"><![CDATA[$F{FieldThatCanBeNull}]]></propertyExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FieldThatCanBeNull}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: I noticed later, almost by chance, that export.json.path + export.json.data solve the problem. The [documentation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.data) doesn't help. I still don't get what is [this](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.repeat.value) for.

Comment: Afaik the net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.repeat.value flag can be set for instance on a text element that appears in a group header but whose value you want repeated in each record on JSON exporting.  In that scenario, if the flag is not set the value would only appear in the first record of the group.

Comment: This solution works fine for String fields. But if you put an Integer field in the expression of export.json.data, it will print null as expected when it evaluates to null, but will throw a cast exception otherwise, claiming the integer can't be cast to String.

Comment: Property values need to be Strings, other values types are not allowed.  But if you convert the integer value to a String, e.g. by using $F{Field}.toString() as property expression, it will be converted back to a number on JSON exporting, as long as the text expression itself was originally an integer.

Comment: Yeah, but this produces an undesirable side effect. The number will be quoted on JSON when it is not null, and the null will be correct (no quotes) when it is null.

Comment: The number shouldn't be quoted if the text field expression is also a number.  At least that's how it worked in my case.  Do you have a small example in which it doesn't work like that?

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/fS30HnaJ) is the example. Now I get that in my case it didn't work because I converted the expression of the Text Field to String too, as I did to the expression on json.data.
Which makes me more confused now. Because the use of json.data should instruct Jasper to ignore the text field expression. Also the decimal point in the Integer.toString() is annoying.

Comment: Right, for numbers it only works as long as the text field expression also produces a number, and for integer values there will be a decimal point in the JSON.  I don't see a better solution at this moment, you can consider logging a bug at https://community.jaspersoft.com/bug-tracker or https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/issues